# How Do You Translate "Everything's Coming up Roses" Into German

Tags: translation

My version is "Alles blühen sowie die Rosen." Is this correct? If not, what would be?

It's the title of a popular Broadway song.

http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/gypsy/everythingscominguproses.htm

Google Translate wasn't much help on this one.

Comment: I think it must be written "Alles blüht, so wie die Rosen." However - there is no "like" in the original, but I don't know the phrase.

Comment: @userunknown: "Like" is implied in the English original. "Everything is coming up [like] roses. In a literal translation, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"*Everything is Coming up Roses"* can not easily be translated to German as there are two meanings intermingled in the title. On one hand there is the literal meaning

> Coming up roses - *rosige Zeiten brechen an*, *Alles wird gut*

On the other hand the title plays with the name of the character Rose who also sings this song. Therefore close but not near as good as the original would be putting it in words like

> Rosige Zeiten für Rose

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps, but a search for "roses" in the PONS English-German dictionary comes up with this entry:
http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=roses&in=&kbd=de&l=deen

> **to come up [***or* **out] [smelling of]** roses ----- bestens laufen *fam*